# Do Frobenius algebras have a lattice basis and what lattices do appear?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, lattice-theory

Let $K$ be for simplicity be the field with two or three elements (or alternatively we could restrict to ideals containing only the field elements $-1$ or $1$ as coefficients).
A (commutative) Frobenius algebra is here a finite dimensional $K$-algebra of the form $A=K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ for $n \geq 1$ where $I$ is an ideal of $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ contained in $J^2$ where $J=\langle x_1,...,x_n\rangle$ such that $A$ has a 1-dimensional socle (basically this means that there is a "unique" largest non-zero monomial modulo $I$).

> Question 1: Does $A$ have a canonical $K$-basis (containing the elements $1,x_1,...,x_n$) of monomials such that those monomials form a lattice under the canonical ordering of monomials?

Maybe one has to restrict further on the algebra to obtain a nice (uniqueness) result.
Note that the number of elements of the possible lattice is equal to the vector space dimension of the algebra.

For example the algebra $K[x_1,x_2]/(x_1^3-x_2^2,x_1 x_2)$ has the canonical basis $1, x_1,x_2,x_1^2,x_1^3 (=x_2^2)$ consisting of 5 elements and the resulting lattice is the pentagon lattice with the cover relations $1>x_1,$ $1>x_2$, $x_1>x_1^2$, $x_1^2>x_1^3$, $x_2>x_1^3(=x_2^2)$.

Another example is $K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1^2,...,x_n^2)$ with basis $1,x_{i_1}...x_{i_l}$ with $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_l \leq n$ corresponding to subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ and the resulting lattice is the Boolean lattice.

More generally the algebras $K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_i^{n_i})$ for $n_i \geq 2$ lead to divisor lattices (product of chains in an obvious way).

> Question 2: Which lattices can appear in that way? Does the lattice determine the algebra?

Obviously such lattices have rather restricted properties. For example the maximum element must cover exactly $n$ elements. Maybe some other structural properties of such lattices are known.

Comment: In socle degree 2 there won’t be such a lattice (unless $n\leq2$), since as you say the maximum element would have to cover $n$ elements. In general the socle degree apparently must be at least $n$ but I doubt that’s sufficient. As these are Arminian Gorenstein algebras they should have nice symmetry, and unimodality if $n\leq3$ etc, but I don’t know how those might be reflected in the basis.